# Security of Content-Type and X-Content-Type-Options headers

Tags: security, http

While going through the material on web application vulnerabilities, I came across some queries. Here are the details.

- The tools like burp, APPScan reports the vulnerabilities based on specific response header from the application server. I understood that there are certain headers which are complementary to one another. For Ex:- 'Content-type' and 'X-Content-Type-Options'. If second is set to 'nosniff', the browser will not sniff the response body at all and will honor the value set in 'Content-Type' header. Similarly, the HTTP request also can indicate the type of response it is expecting using 'Accept' kind of headers. In such cases, do I need to consider application vulnerable if 'X-Content-Type-Options' is not set to 'nosniff' while the request for such response has 'Accept' parameter indicating media type only to text/plain?
- The other extension to this query is that if the response header has the following fields set. `Content-Type=text/plain X-Content-Type-Options=nosinff`. In my opinion, this is not a vulnerability since second parameter will restrict browser from sniffing the response body. Is my understanding correct from security perspective ?

Comment: just because the header is set to "nosinff" dose not stop the vulnerability as with all types of headers they can be changed by the client and not a full prof way to assure security.

Answer (score 0):

From an attacker's perspective, your entire http request to the server is nothing more than a block of strings.  The attacker is not likely to use a standard browser to perform attacks.  It would be something more like a script that just bumps out http requests or a proxy tool that intercepts the request and allows any form of modification.  The "nosniff" flag won't matter to these types of request modification.  Never trust the contents of http requests since they can be dictated by the users in its entirety.